# Plotly: How to interactively set heatmap colorscale using buttons?

Tags: python, plotly

I am using Plotly to make some heatmaps. I would like to have an interactive color bar in order to be able to shift and/or change the scale, the same way as for the x and y axes but for the color scale. As a MWE consider the first code in [this link](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/#basic-heatmap-with-plotlygraphobjects):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
                    z=[[1, 20, 30],
                      [20, 1, 60],
                      [30, 60, 1]]))
fig.show()
```

The x,y default functionality I want to replicate in the color bar can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjYP_wvqf04&feature=youtu.be). Basically I want to partially replicate the functionality of [SAOImageDS9](https://sites.google.com/cfa.harvard.edu/saoimageds9). This functionality can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/G77RcsAfMGM?t=296), if you right click and move the mouse you can change the color scale.

Comment: I am using plotly to plot results from analyses I do with Python, I would prefer to keep it simple. Also I need the standalone HTML file that plotly produces, I don't think this is possible with dash.

Comment: mmmmmm maybe. I would have to see it before knowing. I am looking for something simple and practical, like the default drag and rescale functions by clicking on the x and y axis but in the color bar, without adding extra buttons or menus.

Comment: I actually think I've got it. For all colorscales available to `go.Heatmap()` by default. Should be in place in a few minutes

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that you would prefer *not* having any kind of button. I really don't think there's any way around that. I've put together a suggestion that uses a button, but ***not Dash***. So you can easily export the whole figure with complete functionality to a `.html` file using, for example, `plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='C:/plotlyplots/heatmapcolorscales.html')`

Answer (score 1):

There may be more elegant ways. But the following suggestion sets up buttons with args for all colors available to `go.Heatmap()` by default by building one figure for every colorscale, "stealing" those colorscales one by one, and then making them available as updates to your figure throgh:

```
# buttons, temporary figures and colorscales
for i, scale in enumerate(scales):
    colors.append(go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=z,colorscale = scale)).data[0].colorscale)
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=scale,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'colorscale':[colors[i]],
                                }, ],
                        )
                  )
```

#### Figure with update button:

[image]

#### Some details about the solution:

So why the hassle with `colors.append(go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=z,colorscale = scale)).data[0].colorscale)`? As I said, there might be more elegant ways. But this approach at least ensures that the colorscales keep the same sructure for all colors in:

```
(Heatmap({
     'colorscale': [[0.0, 'rgb(237, 229, 207)'], [0.16666666666666666, 'rgb(224,
                    194, 162)'], [0.3333333333333333, 'rgb(211, 156, 131)'], [0.5,
                    'rgb(193, 118, 111)'], [0.6666666666666666, 'rgb(166, 84, 97)'],
                    [0.8333333333333334, 'rgb(129, 55, 83)'], [1.0, 'rgb(84, 31,
                    63)']],
     'z': [[1, 20, 30], [20, 1, 60], [30, 60, 1]]
 }),)
```

Which is the structure you're editing through buttons and updatemenu.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# data
z=[[1, 20, 30],
  [20, 1, 60],
  [30, 60, 1]]

# every colorscale available to go.Heatmap() by default
scales =     ['aggrnyl', 'agsunset', 'algae', 'amp', 'armyrose', 'balance',
             'blackbody', 'bluered', 'blues', 'blugrn', 'bluyl', 'brbg',
             'brwnyl', 'bugn', 'bupu', 'burg', 'burgyl', 'cividis', 'curl',
             'darkmint', 'deep', 'delta', 'dense', 'earth', 'edge', 'electric',
             'emrld', 'fall', 'geyser', 'gnbu', 'gray', 'greens', 'greys',
             'haline', 'hot', 'hsv', 'ice', 'icefire', 'inferno', 'jet',
             'magenta', 'magma', 'matter', 'mint', 'mrybm', 'mygbm', 'oranges',
             'orrd', 'oryel', 'peach', 'phase', 'picnic', 'pinkyl', 'piyg',
             'plasma', 'plotly3', 'portland', 'prgn', 'pubu', 'pubugn', 'puor',
             'purd', 'purp', 'purples', 'purpor', 'rainbow', 'rdbu', 'rdgy',
             'rdpu', 'rdylbu', 'rdylgn', 'redor', 'reds', 'solar', 'spectral',
             'speed', 'sunset', 'sunsetdark', 'teal', 'tealgrn', 'tealrose',
             'tempo', 'temps', 'thermal', 'tropic', 'turbid', 'twilight',
             'viridis', 'ylgn', 'ylgnbu', 'ylorbr', 'ylorrd']

# scales = scales[10:13]
colors =[]
buttons = []

# buttons, temporary figures and colorscales
for i, scale in enumerate(scales):
    colors.append(go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=z,colorscale = scale)).data[0].colorscale)
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=scale,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'colorscale':[colors[i]],
                                }, ],
                        )
                  )

# Initial figure:
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=z, colorscale = scales[0]))

# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu = []
your_menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)
updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)

# f = fig.
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer. However I am looking for something different. I have added a few links in my question to better illustrate. It may not be possible to do that, however.

Comment: @user171780 No, that's not possible.